# How to upload a Python file from a Python script?

Tags: windows, micropython, python-3.10, raspberry-pi-pico

I am trying to write a script that can create a Python file from multiple inputs and upload it to a Raspberry Pi Pico that has MicroPython installed.
I tried rshell:

```
import subprocess
cmds = 'python -m venv venv & venv\Scripts\activate & pip install rshell pyreadlline3 & rshell & connect serial COM3'
ret = subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True, shell=True)
ret.stdout.decode()
```

A subprocess cannot type commands into rshell. I cannot find a way to upload it. Is there a library I am missing, or is it not possible?

Answer (score 0):

If `rshell` doesn't work for you I would try [`ampy`](https://pypi.org/project/adafruit-ampy/)

> MicroPython Tool (ampy) - Utility to interact with a CircuitPython or
> MicroPython board over a serial connection.
>
> Ampy is meant to be a simple command line tool to manipulate files and
> run code on a CircuitPython or MicroPython board over its serial
> connection. With ampy you can send files from your computer to the
> board's file system, download files from a board to your computer, and
> even send a Python script to a board to be executed.

pip install adafruit-ampy

Then you must find the serial port on which your baord is connected to the PC and then

To run a file on the board without uploading it

```
ampy --port /dev/ttyXXXX run main.py
```

To upload a file

```
ampy --port /dev/ttyXXXX put main.py
```

To remove a file:

```
ampy --port /dev/ttyXXXX rm main.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You can somehow utilize [`mpremote`](https://pypi.org/project/mpremote/) through the backdoor. The only drawback is the missing `stdout/stderr` capturing as it is defined in [`mpremote/pyboard.py`](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/294baf52b346e400e2255c6c1e82af5b978b18f7/tools/pyboard.py#L78-L82), so using [`redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) is not working out of the box

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Optional, Sequence, Tuple

from mpremote import commands
from mpremote import main as mpr_main
from mpremote import mip


@dataclass
class MyArgs:
    device: Sequence[str]
    follow: bool = True
    expr: Sequence[str] = field(default_factory=list)
    eval: Sequence[str] = field(default_factory=list)
    recursive: bool = False
    verbose: bool = False
    command: Sequence[str] = field(default_factory=list)
    path: Tuple[str, ...] = field(default_factory=list)
    do_run_command: bool = False
    mpy: bool = True
    target: Optional[str] = None
    index: Optional[str] = None
    packages: Sequence[str] = field(default_factory=list)


def main():
    args = MyArgs(
        # connect to the device
        device=["/dev/ttyACM0"],
        #
        # execute the string on the device
        # expr=["import micropython; micropython.mem_info()"],
        #
        # evaluate and print the result of a Python expression
        # eval=["1/2"],
        #
        # list all files on the device
        # command=["ls"],
        #
        # copy the file "changelog.md" from the parent dir to the device
        # command=["cp"],
        # path=["../changelog.md", ":changelog.md"],
        #
        # copy the folder "tests" recursively to the device
        # command=["cp"],
        # recursive=True,
        # path=["tests/", ":"],
        #
        # remove the file "changelog.md" from the device
        # command=["rm"],
        # path=["changelog.md"],
        #
        # run given local script
        # do_run_command=True,
        # path=["boot.py"],
        #
        # install some mip package
        # command=["install"],
        # packages=[
        #     "umqtt.simple",
        #     "github:brainelectronics/micropython-modbus",
        # ],
    )
    print(args)

    state = mpr_main.State()
    commands.do_connect(state=state, args=args)

    if args.expr:
        commands.do_exec(state=state, args=args)

    if args.eval:
        args.expr = args.eval
        commands.do_eval(state=state, args=args)

    if args.command and not args.packages:
        commands.do_filesystem(state=state, args=args)

    if args.do_run_command:
        commands.do_run(state=state, args=args)

    if args.packages:
        mip.do_mip(state=state, args=args)

    commands.do_disconnect(state)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```